# Merge balak tag into parashat-balak tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, merge-tag-request

In keeping with the tags for other parshiot (search for 'parashat' on the [tags page](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags)), can the *balak* tag be merged into the *parashat-balak* tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done.